# Not able to generate a pdf using jspdf

Tags: jquery

I created a simple form to see how `jspdf` works and expand the form once comfortable.

Here is the simple form I created:

```
<form id="smdiv">
    <div id="content">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <label>Info</label>
        <input type="text" name="info"/>
        <label>ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

And the script below is what I found through my research:

```
<script>
$('#cmd').click(function () {
    var name_val = $('form#smdiv input[name="name"]').val();
    var info_val = $('form#smdiv input[name="info"]').val();
    var id_val = $('form#smdiv input[name="id"]').val();

    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    pdf.text(5, 5, 'You figure out formatting');
    pdf.text(30, 30, 'Name: '+ name_val);
    pdf.text(60, 60, 'Info: '+ info_val);
    pdf.text(90, 90, 'ID: '+ id_val);
    pdf.save('hello_world.pdf');
});
```

and the following scripts I am calling:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>
```

However, when I try to click on the button to generate the pdf, no pdf's are generated (reference button below). I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Am I calling the wrong jquery scripts to make this work? Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>
```

Here is what i did:

```
  <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Convert to pdf file</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="images/styleregal.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.2/jspdf.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#cmd').click(function () {
            var name_val = $('form#smdiv input[name="name"]').val();
            var info_val= $('form#smdiv input[name="info"]').val();
            var id_val = $('form#smdiv input[name="id"]').val();

            var pdf = new jsPDF();
            pdf.text(5, 5, 'You figure out formatting');
            pdf.text(30, 30, 'Name: '+ name_val);
            pdf.text(60, 60, 'Info: '+ info_val);
            pdf.text(90, 90, 'ID: '+ id_val);
            pdf.save('hello_world.pdf');
        }); 
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="smdiv">
    <div id="content">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="name"/>
        <label>Info</label>
        <input type="text" name="info"/>
        <label>ID</label>
        <input type="text" name="id"/>
    </div>
</form>
<button id="cmd">generate PDF</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: your code works for me, here is the fiddle  https://jsfiddle.net/pvjtamh0/2/

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: Is it the order I have my scripts srources. I have tried and it isnt working on my end. I get the following error when I look at the debugger tool: jsPDF is undefined. Should the script be in the header?

Comment: I don't think so... I added those in the same order that you have

Comment: try putting you click event within document.ready

Comment: Head tag will be a good place

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: I tried putting in the head tag and still throws the same error. I will post the whole code for you to see

Comment: I just copy pasted your code into an HTML file and it still works for me, your best bet is to maybe download local copies of the 3 js files and provide that path instead of sites

Comment: @KarthikGanesan okay. I will do that. Thought it would be easier to call the sites

Comment: @KarthikGanesan I tried that and it appears that the files and site have errors. Is there a site where I can reference to?

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: I also tried through angular and gives out a similiar error. let me see what i am doing wrong

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: After some time, I figured out why its breaking and I have a question for you: How can I make this work, but for IE 10 and below?

Comment: try using jQuery 1.12.0... here is the link for supported browser https://jquery.com/browser-support/

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: I am able to get the rest of the form to work correctly in IE, meaning checks users inputs. However, it is still throwing the error out of jsPDF. I am getting "Array Buffer undefined"

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: In my research, I found that I need to implement the following fix using this. But I try, still errors out
 https://github.com/inexorabletash/polyfill/blob/master/typedarray.js

Comment: check this link... hope this helps https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/blob/master/libs/html2canvas/readme.md

Comment: @KarthikGanesan Thank you for your assistance. I have also looked into this and does convert it to pdf. The issue I am seeing is when opening the pdf file in adobe, the content of the pdf is unreadable.

Comment: @KarthikGanesan: I think I found a solution. Thank you for your help. Was very educational

Comment: you're welcome.. you should probably post your solution here which can be helpful for others